# How to find out what causes Driver locked

Tags: memory, performance, windows-8.1

My computer is running slow, so I decided to use [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx). I've found out that "Driver locked" has allocated about 10 GB of RAM.

I've searched the internet, and found out that programs like VMWare, Fancy Cache, or Windows Server can cause this, but I don't have any of them installed.

How can I find the program that causes this?

Comment: Which driver is using the memory?  If you start up with a minimal start-up configuration is this memory locked still?

Comment: Have you activated Hyper-V in Windows 8.1?